# GIS area calculation

Tags: php, python, ruby, gis, area

I am developing a web based system where I need to distrubute areas in a map for diferent people and purposes.

I have a **delimited area** with **irregular borders** that will be shared between different persons.

For instance:

```
Person 1: 3.000m2
Person 2: 5.000m2
Person 3: 10.000m2
```

I need to distrubute those values in the area and show them in a map. I'm having a hard time finding a way to define the perimeter for each person minding the irregular borders of my initial area.

Questions:

- GIS etensions for popular databases like PostGIS or PHPGis can help me on this?
- Are there any libs or well known algorithm to calculate it?
- Popular web-based frameworks, like geodjango, has this kind of function?

I'm not limited to a specific language, anything helps, ruby, python, php, c#, javascript.

Regards.

Comment: Do the territories have to be contiguous?

Comment: not always, but sometimes it will be.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to the availability of this in popular frameworks. But given your description of distributing areas and irregular borders I suggest you look into software that does redistricting, aka gerrymandering.  One source might be the [Public Mapping Project](http://www.publicmapping.org/resources/software) Another might be [redistricter](https://code.google.com/p/redistricter/)